# List of bluetoothctl : paired-devices is empty after a reboot

Tags: bluetooth

I can connect a device to my (headless, if it counts) Raspberry Pi 3B through Bluetooth protocol using the following steps : 
bluetoothctl and on this program, I run

```
 - agent on
 - default agent
 - pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

prompt for the exchanged key ok

```
 - connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
 - trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

Then I can check that

```
bluetoothctl # paired-devices
```

indeed contains my device.

But after a reboot, and check of the same command, the list is empty, and I need to do again all the pairing steps.

How to remedy to this problem and keep the list of all devices somewhere ?

I think that the main problem I have to reconnect automatically after reboot, which is what I ultimately would like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Devices List not being remembered on reboot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43648/bluetooth-devices-list-not-being-remembered-on-reboot)

Comment: Sorry, I realised the solution was already discussed somewhere else : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/43648/82347.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of Stack Exchange.  It is always a good idea to search for questions that might already exist that answer your burning question directly.  (As you also note) a duplicate already exists so this one will get closed off pretty quickly - but don't be afraid to ask something else! 8-)